# Angular4 routing: Dynamic string parameter in path

Tags: angular, angular4-router

Passing ints as path parameters is done like

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {
        path: 'servers/:id',
        component: ServerDetailComponent
    }]
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

but how do I do the same with `:id` being a `string`? So that I could navigate the servers object, say, by `name`, instead of `id`, like `/servers/sqlserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send strings the same way as numbers.  It makes no difference between strings or numbers.

```
path: 'servers/:name',
```